# Why that query return always 1 any time?

Tags: mysql, date, time

Why that query return always 1 any time?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%Y/%m/%d 00:30:00') >= '2017-11-22 16:00:00' <= DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%Y/%m/%d 15:00:00')
```

I have that query in ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO daprenotare (prodotto, quantita, terminale, data)
VALUES (:prodotto, :quantita, :terminale, NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
data = IF((quantita = :quantita AND terminale = :terminale) AND (IF((DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%Y/%m/%d 00:30') >= data <= DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%Y/%m/%d 15:00')) = 1, 'TRUE', 'FALSE')  AND CURTIME() >= '15'), '$data', data)
```

I would like to do something as:

- if data(value in db) is equal to today, the time is between 00:30 and 15:00 and CURTIME is later than the 15: UPDATE date
- if data(value in db) is equal to today, the time is between 15:00 and 00:30 and CURTIME is later than the 00:30: UPDATE date

Answer (score 0):

because you dont have AND operator, also you are using `/` and `-` to separate the dates.

```
SELECT '2017/11/22 00:10:00' >= DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%Y/%m/%d 00:30:00') 
   AND '2017/11/22 00:10:00' <= DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%Y/%m/%d 15:00:00') as t1, 
       '2017/11/22 15:00:00' >= DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%Y/%m/%d 00:30:00') 
   AND '2017/11/22 15:00:00' <= DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%Y/%m/%d 15:00:00') as t2;
```

You could use `BETWEEN` so doesn't have to repeat

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/MLBCZ80331)**

```
SELECT '2017/11/22 00:10:00' BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%Y/%m/%d 00:30:00')
                                 AND DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%Y/%m/%d 15:00:00') as t1,
       '2017/11/22 15:00:00' BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%Y/%m/%d 00:30:00')
                                 AND DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%Y/%m/%d 15:00:00') as t2;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: the first return every time 1, the second return every time 0

Comment: Check the edit. you are using `/` and `-` use the same

Comment: i need to extract '2017/11/22 16:00:00'  from TIME(data) and so i have 2017-11-22

Comment: Check include demo

Comment: The problem is you make two different question. We only answer the first one we saw :(. For the second one you should provide sample data and expected output. But the syntaxis for the conditional should  be the same

Comment: Your first query return 0 every time!

Comment: Please check again

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `date_format()` of `curdate()`?  Why are you converting a date to a string to compare to a date?  It is already a date!

How about:

```
select date_add(curdate(), interval 30 minute) >= '2017-11-22 16:00:00' and
       '2017-11-22 16:00:00' <= date_add(curdate(), interval 15 hour)
```

Comment: it return every time 0

Comment: @stacks You are doing something wrong. Check the demo [**here**](http://rextester.com/PMUJZ69558)

Comment: That query return 0 with every time